# How to make a div 100% height

Tags: html, css, height

Hello everyone first of all sorry for asking a question that have already been asked so many times. Forgive me with that said i have not been able to find an answer that matches and works with my code that is why i am asking :)

Well I want to make my sidebar div 100% height and not just adjust to content inside the div how to i do that?

Here is my code:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}

.SideMenu {
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    background-color:#ACB9B1;
    width:20%;
    margin:0;
    overflow-y:hidden;  
    overflow-x:hidden;  
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u9r7zeyk/ Here it shows at full height, don't know why?

Comment: Please show your code in **JS Fiddle** or in **Stack Snippest**

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/u9r7zeyk/ Here it shows at full height in there dont know why?

Comment: Kind of hard for us to solve your problem if we can't see it. :)

Comment: I don't understand what you want exactly.

Comment: Guys please look here http://imgur.com/uFUciqA for a visual i want that grey div in the left side to be height 100% of the browser window no matter how much content i have on the page Thanks!

Comment: I think percentage heights only work if parent element also floats

Comment: Not sure about that but anyway i found a work around as i have uploaded you may see it if you want :) thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello huys thanks for the inputs what i did you can see here:

```
.menu{
background-color:#ACB9B1;
width: 200px;
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
bottom: 0px;    
}   

.menu li a {
display:block;
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
line-height: 1.5;
margin-left:5%;
color:#A92432;
           }
.menu li {
width: 100%;

height: 30px;
font-family: 'Open Sans';
border-bottom: 1px solid #A92432;;
font-size:18px;
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
}

.SideMenu {
    height:100%;
    background-color:#ACB9B1;
    width:20%;
}
```

Comment: Please try to explain what you want exactly.

Comment: please look here http://imgur.com/uFUciqA for a visual i want that grey div in the left side to be height 100% of the browser window no matter how much content i have on the page Thanks!

Comment: Please, add details to your answer for help everyone to understand where is the magic.

Answer (score 0):

Edited, Here you go. I think this is what you want.

```
html, body {
        margin: 0px;

    }

    .SideMenu {
        position:absolute;
        height:100%;
        float:left;
        background-color:#ACB9B1;
        width:20%;
        margin:0;
        overflow-y:hidden;  
        overflow-x:hidden;  
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u9r7zeyk/2/

Comment: No as you see in your example the div stops when the content inside the div does i want the div to be height 100% of browsers window hope you understand :)

Comment: @Anoxy, Check it now.